# How do you set Flutter build options in Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter, build

I need to set the following flutter build option in the Xcode GUI:

--no-tree-shake-icons

Without this, I get an error when building an Archive for distribution (which I would like ignored).

I'm guessing that somewhere buried in the Xcode settings is the "flutter build ..." command, but cannot find it.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the answer!

In Xcode, open the Runner/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig file. In there you should find the following:

TREE_SHAKE_ICONS=true

Set it to false and re-run Archive. If its missing, just add it.

I think this file gets generated by Android Studio when you build your flutter app, so you may need to change it each time you need to do a release. But it works!